# Listview displaying cardview creating redundancy

Tags: android

I have a listview and it has 2 cardview in every row. I set cardview using custom adapter but problem is when i have odd no of items in my list then one cardview is filled with random view.how to solve this?

[image]

In this last cardview in last row is set randomly.

Comment: Use a `GridView` or hide the other card.

Comment: your gridview suggestion works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

If you display 2 items per row, then the number of items you return in your adapter is (num_items + 1) / 2;

When you get the call for getView(), if the position is ((num_items + 1) / 2) (last row), then if the number of items is odd, for the 2nd card view you do not populate anything and set its visibility to INVISIBLE.

What you see is a recycled card view holding previous values.

Comment: its not working . when i scroll up it sets some other cardview to invisible.

Comment: Just set it to visible in all other scenarios - when you're not on the last row.